# Why elements width is different with position: relative?

Tags: html, css

If I remove `position: relative;` from the anchor element, then all elements have same width, but with position: relative; they are of different size?

First 2 element ~48px, third element - ~44px.
How I can fix it?

```css
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";

a {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: "How I can fix it" what is there to fix? what is the poblem you've hit? do they need widths? can this be set in the css and inline-block them??

Comment: For me (Firefox) `position: relative` makes no difference. But when you remove any whitespace between `<a>` and `<i>` (before and after), the problem is gone.

Comment: It's not because of `position: relative` - you have whitespace between the elements and that's cousing that - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np3av855/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found inline elements to behave strangely when adding padding to them, if you just make the anchors inline-block, it will also solve your issue:

```css
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";

a {
  display:inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`position:relative` is not the one causing the issue, but the formatting of the `HTML`. Try writing it like this:

```css
@import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
 a {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i></a>
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i></a>
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-anchor"></i></a>
```

Comment: Your variant works great too, but in future this markup will be generated by php, so I cant control formatting.